# Designing a mentoring system over GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am developing a system that has a list of projects (verified by mentors) to which a student can provide a solution. Now I am stuck in a situation about how the student will submit their solution for review by our mentors.

The student will fork our project repository (problem statement, initial code and tests) and work on it until completion. Then they will have to submit it to get reviewed. I want to make this submission and reviewing part to be transparent and visible on both mentor and student's GitHub profile so that they can show their work to others.

The problem that I am facing is that a mentor cannot review a repository until the student creates a pull request to the original project repo. But if they do it would update the project repo's code which we don't want because we want more than one student to attempt the solution to the problem, as we want them to have more programming experience of solving real world problems.

Comment: You don't have to *merge* the pull request.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes. That could be a possible solution but then there would be a lot of pull request.

Comment: So what? You can close them unmerged once they've been reviewed, or use tags to indicate their status, or ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, that would be much better. One more side of problem is how to handle plagiarism. What do you think should we check plagiarism or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [duplicate the repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/duplicating-a-repository) and have the student send the PR to the duplicated repo.

This may seem excessive. As @jonrsharpe said in the comment, you don't have to merge the PR. And even if you do, you could always have the students send the PR to a side-branch. So why duplicate?

Because you want to make it *private*!

GitHub is all about high visibility, and you don't want one student's work to be available to the other students. The base task repositories can be public, but once a student choose a repository you should make a private duplicate of it and only give the student and the mentor (and other staff members that need access to it? your call) access to it. The student's fork should also be private, of course, so other students can't copy their work.

Comment: Thanks you very much. The problem is two way sword. I want the high visibility of the work student/mentor do but also don't want the student to just copy and paste other student's work and show it as their own. What do you think?

Comment: Since you insist on having the student's work publicly visible, the only way to stop plagiarism is to check their works against each other's - either manually or with an automatic checker. The fact that part of the task is a communication with a mentor inside a PR can really help here - it's harder to plagiarize a conversation. Assuming you can enforce a few cycles of PR rejects and fixes...

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it works very well. But, I didn't quite get the part in which you describe about how to go about preventing plagiarism (last two lines).

Comment: @AhmedBilal - Idan's suggesting that the mentor doesn't just review and close, but does a few back-and-forths of questions, refactors, maybe changes requirements after the PR is submitted. Thus the whole interaction is both helping the student, *and* preventing plagarism (because you can't plagarize a refactor that other students haven't done, and you can't plagarize the reason you did X instead of Y - and if the answer is terrible, you may have just noticed some possible plagarism). Only smallish changes - like saying an API call should return a map of ID:object instead of an array of objects

Comment: @Delioth Thanks. Now, It makes sense to me.